# rails - devise strong parameters is always unpermitted for registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to permit **:full_name** parameter for my user model registration in devise, and I always getting **Unpermitted parameter: :full_name** as response for Users::RegistrationsController#create action

I have tried several ways as I show you next:

**1. Application controller (option 1)**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  
  protected
  
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    case params[:action]
    when 'create'
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[full_name])
    when 'update'
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

Result => Unpermitted parameter: :full_name

**2. Registration controller (option 2)**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: :create
  
  protected
  
  def configure_sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(%i[full_name])
  end
end
```

Result => Unpermitted parameter: :full_name

**3. Registration controller (option 3)**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: :create
  
  protected
  
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[full_name ])
  end
end
```

Result => Unpermitted parameter: :full_name

**In my gemfile:**

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.8'
```

**In my routes:**

```
devise_controllers = {
  confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
  registrations: 'users/registrations',
  invitations: 'users/invitations',
}
devise_for :users, controllers: devise_controllers
```

I have read [devise strong params](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters) but to be honest I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Also I tried to debug in Users::RegistrationsController#create what is happening with:

```
def create
  super do
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

but it skips the debugger breakpoint... do you have any idea what is going on?

Cheers!

**Edit:**

- Following suggestion from JohnP, I only left :full_name in devise keys parametter sanitizer for sign_up
- Also I removed a callback that is bypassing my debug breakpoint and now I can stop with pry in create action

Comment: Is the `configure_sign_up_params` before action being executed? I'd put a `binding.pry` inside that method to make sure that's actually being executed

Comment: @arieljuod yes, it is being executed :( if I do ´params[:user]´ ´<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"abc@mail.com", "full_name"=>"carlos", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password"} permitted: false>´

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you write strong params for a specific controller, not in your ApplicationController, because the permitted conditions will be different for each model. When using `devise_parameter_sanitizer`, you only need to include the extra fields you're adding - this isn't setting up your strong params from scratch, just adding keys to the default Devise list.

So, you should find that this is all you need in your Users::RegistrationsController.

```rb
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name])
end
```

(BTW, ensure you refer to the parameter correctly, as `params[:user][:full_name]`.)

(Oh, and if you want to do debugging, I'd suggest installing the byebug gem. You just add an extra line `byebug` where you want to have a breakpoint.)

Comment: Thanks for answer, your are right in rails console devise_parameter_sanitizer print sign_up, sign_in, account_update keys and I just being duplicating them, regardless that I follow your advice is not working, same result Unpermitted parameter :full_name. BTW, I am doing binding.pry instead of byebug for debug.

Comment: How are you trying to use the parameter? Are you using `params[:user][:full_name]` or `params[:full_name]`?

Comment: As I know, in the docs from devise I do not have to point to :user because devise_parameter_sanitizer is taking the name of the resource from where devise is "installed" in this case the model User, so my @resource_name is :user, or I have to do keys: [user: :full_name]? something like that?

Comment: Have you tried `params[:user][:full_name]`? That's what I use and it works here in the `User::RegistrationsController`.

Comment: Can you show me your User::RegistrationController configure_sign_up_params function for reference, please?

Comment: It's just one line: `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :organisation_id])`. And then I use params like this in `#create`: `_email = Sanitiser::String.new.call(params[:user][:email])` and so forth. (As you'll see, that's actually referencing one of the standard Devise fields, `email`, and not even one of those I've added.) In general, the easiest way to debug something like this is to use binding.pry or whatever, stick a breakpoint in there and just look at the structure of your `params`.

Comment: Still no working, `[1] pry(#<Users::RegistrationsController>)> sign_up_params
Unpermitted parameter: :full_name
=> {"email"=>"abc@abc.cc", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password"}
` I belive that `devise_parameter_sanitizer` is adding :full_name but for some reason is being ignored. I am very stuck at this point.

Comment: What is the straight `params` result?

Comment: It is fixed! The problem was that a prepend_before_action callback method (recaptcha) is calling `resource.validate` and is throwing a validation error and returning a `render :new` for more context, a user belongs to an account, account is the parent table, so it needs to be created before the user, to achive that behaviour in check_recaptcha method, I only add `resource.build_account` this do the trick for the validation, this method returns the resource, and in #create action in RegistrationController I do `super do; resource.build_account; resource.save; blahblah end`, so it passes...

Comment: BTW :full_name error has nothing to do with the account validation relation I think, the fact that is showing me that error is anoying, but who knows? @JohnP thanks for your time :)

Comment: Well, I'm glad you found the answer! 